# Access - Selecting unique rows with newest date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access database table to track assignments between laptops and vehicles called Records, which shows ComputerName, the UnitNumber it's assigned to, and the date that assignment was recorded.

```
ID  ComputerName    UnitNumber  DateRecorded
1   LT150           5010        8/1/2015
2   LT150           788         8/30/2015
3   LT235           4009        8/4/2015
4   LT150           123         9/21/2015
```

Now I'm trying to find a way to query those results to only show unique ComputerName for the most recent DateRecorded.

So the results would be

```
ComputerName    UnitNumber  DateRecorded
LT150           123         9/21/2015
LT235           4009        8/4/2015
```

I can't figure out how to make that query work. This is what I tried, but it gives me an aggregate function error.

```
SELECT 
    ComputerName, MAX(DateRecorded) as RecetDate,
    UnitNumber 
FROM 
    Records 
GROUP BY 
    ComputerName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `GROUP BY` for this type of query.

Instead:

```
select r.*
from Records as r
where r.DateRecorded = (select max(r2.DateRecorded)
                        from Records as r2
                        where r2.ComputerName = r.ComputerName
                       );
```

Note:  this assumes that the same date is not used twice for the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the error because you are missing a field in your group by statement. Try this

```
SELECT ComputerName, MAX(DateRecorded) as RecetDate,UnitNumber FROM Records 
GROUP BY ComputerName,UnitNumber;
```